# Python - flask - understanding behaviour of routing / flash()

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm new to this. I can't understand why the app doesn't seem to be able to keep hold of data that was randomly generated. get_question() returns a dict with 2 key:value pairs. The question/answer are randomly generated from this function. Every time flash() is called does it rerun all of the code inside index()? When the flashed messages appear, the user's answer correlates to what was typed in, but the question and correct answer seem to appear at random - suggesting that the whole of index() is recalled every time submit is clicked. How do I prevent that from happening? Should I be using 'session'?

UPDATE: To be more specific - I can't understand why the flashed messages are completely unrelated to what is rendered in the browser. It seems as though flash() is running its own call to my get_question() function and as a result is getting different questions/answers to the ones shown?

[Here are some images that show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe2yT.png)

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'test'}  # fake user
    question = question_gen.get_question()
    answer = AnswerQuestionForm()
    q = question['question']
    correct = question['answer']
    response = ""

    if answer.validate_on_submit():
        you_said = request.form['answer']


        print("You said {}, to the question {}. correct was {}".format(you_said, q, correct))

        flash("The question was: %s" % q)
        flash("The correct answer was: %s" % correct)
        flash("You said: %s" % you_said)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))


    return render_template('index.html',
                           title='Home',
                           user=user,
                           question=question,
                           answer=answer,
                           response=response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of `flash` like a filing cabinet.  When you run the `flash('message')` command all it does it store that message in the cabinet.  If your templates aren't actively looking in the cabinet for messages and taking them out, they'll just keep building up.  Sometimes that is confusing if you're not immediately grabbing them on the next page, because when you do finally check for them, the feedback that was generated at that point is now shown when it's not longer useful (and likely is now confusing).

So if we assume a simple app like:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'SO'

@app.route('/')
def store():
    flash('Stored at {}'.format(datetime.now()))
    return 'Reload to store another message!'


@app.route('/contents/')
def contents():
    return render_template('contents.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

With the contents of `contents.html` being:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Messages</title>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

If I go to `/` ten times, then load up `/contents/` It'll render my `contents.html` template and display any waiting messages, essentially the template code is going "Open the filing cabinet and pull out and display each stored message, then throw it away".  Generally the template code above is included on **every** page template, so the flashed feedback is immediate and doesn't build up.

**Update**

If you look at your program flow, the first time a user accesses the page without a form submission, the following happens:

1. Get random question
2. Render the `index.html` template using the random question

When a user fills in the answer and submits the form, the following happens:

1. Get a new random question
2. Pull the `answer` field from the form
3. Print the `answer` field from the form, the new randomly generated `question` and the new randomly generated `answer`.
4. Flash the same information
5. Redirect the user to the `index` view

At this point, nothing's been shown to the user, the (incorrect) flashed messages are already in the cabinet, but we're not finished because of the redirect:

6. Get another random question
7. Render the `index` template using the random question

What you're missing is the ability to look up an existing question, when the form is submitted you need some logic to say "get me the question that matches this submitted form entry so I can check the answer is correct".

Usually that's done with a `id` key  `question = {id: 1, question: "1+1", answer: "2"}`  Then you could store that `id` as a hidden field in your form and adjust your `get_question` to optionally take an `id` argument so it can look through your list of questions to find the correct one.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful - I've added some images to show my specific problem. How can I get flash() to recognise the questions that are coming up in the browser rather than how it seemingly goes and gets its own questions?

Comment: Thanks again for your help - I can't ID the questions/answers as they are based on random number generation, not randomly selected from a list. Any idea how I should go about this?

Comment: You likely have an original list of questions, so there is an order.  If I gave you that list and then I threw a pair of dice, I could say "I randomly picked question... 4". You could then look down to the forth question to find the one I meant.

Comment: Not that simple I'm afraid.. Each question is based on three random variables: 2 integers ranging from 1-255 and one of a possible six number conversation methods.

Comment: It doesn't change the solution.  If you need three pieces of information to rebuild the correct question and answer, then you need to store all three pieces of information in the form-- that way when the user submits the form, you have all the information you need to reconstruct the question, so you're able to check the answer.